Sum of two random variables has same distribution as sum of two uniform
Let $U$, $V$ be two independant random variables with uniform distribution on $\{1, \dots, n \}$.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independant random variables, each with values in $\{1, \dots, n \}$ such that $X+Y$ has the same probability distribution as $U+V$.
Is it true that $X$ and $Y$ have both uniform distributions on $\{1, \dots, n \}$ ?

Yes, they are both uniform distributed on ${1, 2, ..., n}$

details please.
